# Ubuntu fails to initramfs *fart*

Tags: boot

Hi so I did a release upgrade today and since nothing will boot.

Whenever I try to boot it fails to `initramfs` and I get the following messages:

```
error getting socket: address family not supported by protocol 
Error initializing use under control socketerror initializing use control socket
Gave up waiting for root device.

ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/81b4d2f3-21d6-4d3b-9e44-a8c52b57f45f does not exist 
Dropping to shell
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Add `unix` at the end. Save, exit and then:

```
sudo update-initramfs -k 4.6.1-040601-generic -u
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This returns no such file or directory.

Comment: It returns no such file if I try to use vim. If I try to use gedit I get another error. Relocation error: /use/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0: GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file list++.so.6 with link time reference